# Redis: Live data via channel

Tags: php, python, redis

I have a weather station supplying me data every 2.5 seconds. (using weewx)
I want to show this live on my website using highcharts to plot live data.
Currently i can pickup the messages from the redis channel 'weather' using Predis just to test.
The issue is that the data is only sent every 2.5, so when a users opens the php site he sometimes has to wait 2.5 seconds for the chart to appear.
Do you have any suggestions to get around this issue?

Comment: what about putting the data in a database/different field in redis and read from that?

Comment: that requires my software to "poll" the DB, now my software can do the changes when the new message is received from the channel

Comment: You can fill the data the first time from the database, and than poll using the way it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is have a second listener dump data into a key current_weather every time an event comes across. When you first load the page, pull from that key to build the chart, *then* start listening for updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the data manually the very first time (while developing the software).
2. Every 2.5 seconds of running, use polling to check for updated data. If the data is updated, then update the data currently stored.

When the user logs on, you plot the chart with the values in the database.